# Facing error "Address already in use" while running locust

Tags: java, python, traceback, locust

While trying to run a locust file and convert the data in csv I'm facing this error in java with the dummy locustfile.py. I have tried editing the command and everything but nothing seems to be helping out. PFB ERROR:

```
locust -f /home/sonali/locustapitest/src/main/resources/performance/locust-master.py --master --no-web --csv=/home/sonali/locustapitest/target/csvlocustsresults/performanceResults --expect-slaves=1 -c 1 -r 1 -t1m
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,897] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,897] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: File "/home/sonali/.local/bin/locust", line 8, in <module>
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,897] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: 
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,897] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: sys.exit(main())
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,897] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: 
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,897] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/locust/main.py", line 503, in main
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: 
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: runners.locust_runner = MasterLocustRunner(locust_classes, options)
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: 
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/locust/runners.py", line 320, in __init__
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: 
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: self.server = rpc.Server(self.master_bind_host, self.master_bind_port)
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: 
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: File "/home/sonali/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/locust/rpc/zmqrpc.py", line 41, in __init__
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: 
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: self.socket.bind("tcp://%s:%i" % (host, port))
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: 
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 550, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 26, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: zmq.error
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: .
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: ZMQError
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: :
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr: Address already in use
[2020-07-07 12:26:25,898] sonali-Latitude-3490/ERROR/stderr:
```

Comment: seems like you already have the address and port used by something else.

Comment: yes, I killed the port and restart, it is working fine now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Check that the address and file you are trying to change **is not opened** or used in another application.

Then try with killing the port number,your server is running on.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by killing the process holding the port as mentioned above. I follow this method to find the pid of the process.

```
lsof -i tcp:8089
```

Then I use the below command to kill the process.

```
kill -9 <pid>
```